# Time based workflow queue is getting emptied

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Couple of days ago I viewed a queue of Time-Based Workflow rules which notify a specific person (by creating tasks and emailing), but today I found this list is empty. This person mentioned that she turned off all notifications. How is that possible that it emptied workflow queue? I don't remember reading about it in any documentation. Is there a way to roll back changes?

**UPDATE #1:**

Workflow rules are active and were not changed in the last couple of days.

**UPDATE #2:**

Yesterday I fixed my rules and using apex triggered WFR to re-evaluate existing records and had my queue populated again... BUT I came in today and it's empty again. How is it possible?

**UPDATE #3:**

I found out that a scheduled apex class was causing an error and for some reason it cleared all WFR. Now it's fixed.

Comment: The Time based workflow might have been deactivated which removed all the records in the Queue.

Comment: @Vignex that is not a source of a problem, all WFR are active and nothing was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's actually triggering? It might be helpful to have a temporary checkbox which gets set as an immediate action to confirm the WFR is triggering. Also it's possible the record not longer matches the criteria, maybe someone has done a mass update?

Note:

> Will the pending actions in the queue ALWAYS fire? No. Time-dependent
>   actions remain in the workflow queue until processed or the rule
>   criteria for the workflow rule is evaluated as false. If a record no
>   longer matches the rule criteria when the rule is evaluated,
>   Salesforce removes the time-dependent actions queued for that record.
>
> For example, an opportunity workflow rule may specify: A criteria set
>   to "Opportunity: Status not equals to Closed Won, Closed Lost." An
>   associated time-dependent action with a time trigger set to seven days
>   before the opportunity close date. If a record that matches the
>   criteria is created on July 1st and the Close Date is set to July
>   30th, the time-dependent action is scheduled for July 23rd. However,
>   if the opportunity is set to "Closed Won" or "Closed Lost" before July
>   23rd, the time-dependent action is automatically removed from the
>   queue.

Taken from:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245

Comment: Yesterday I fixed my rules and using apex triggered WFR to re-evaluate existing records and had my queue populated again... BUT I came today and it's empty again. Doesn't make sense.